# Spark SQL Execution failed. Getting java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.227] failure: ``union'' expected but `.' found

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running Spark 1.6 version, I am experimenting remote data process with spark. After getting data from remote database using JDBC I have created spark data frame and saved temporarily as table using `registerTempTable('')` method. Up to this far it is working. When I run a query in spark context I am getting this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 580, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._ssql_ctx.sql(sqlQuery), self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o21.sql.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.227] failure: ``union'' expected but `.' found
```

I am using pyspark in command prompt, here is my code:

```py
from pyspark import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options( 
    url='jdbc:sqlserver://<ipaddress>;user=xyz;password=pw',
    dbtable='JOURNAL'
).load()
df.registerTempTable('JOURNAL')

df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(
    url='jdbc:sqlserver:<ipaddress>;user=xyz;password=pw',
    dbtable='GHIS'
).load()
df.registerTempTable('GHIS')

df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(
    url='jdbc:sqlserver:<ip address>;user=xyz;password=pw',
    dbtable='LEAS'
).load()
df.registerTempTable('LEAS')
```

*up to this far I am getting and loading data*

Now, here I have got the problem:

```py
doubtaccount = sqlContext.sql("SELECT  ENTITYID as EntityID,SUBSTRING(DESCRPN,1,CHARINDEX('-',DESCRPN,1)-1) as BldgID,SUBSTRING(DESCRPN,CHARINDEX('-',DESCRPN,1)+1,20) as LeaseID,PERIOD*100+15 as TxnDateInt,PERIOD as Period,0-AMT as BDAmt FROM BI_Staging.dbo.JOURNAL where SOURCE = 'DA' and ACCTNUM = 'RE078201000' and STATUS = 'P' ")
```

When I run this query I have faced the problem above. I have searched for similar errors in stack overflow but I did not find any. Is there anything wrong in my query? This actually worked in the database.

Answer (score 1):

*Edited*

When you did `df.registerTempTable('JOURNAL')`, you made the dataframe available to sqlContext with the name `JOURNAL` so your query must access it by this name:

```py
doubtaccount = sqlContext.sql("SELECT  ... FROM JOURNAL where ... ")
```

However, please note that this query will be parsed by spark, and not by your database, so the syntax must be hive-compatible.

If you want your query to be executed in the database, before loading the data into spark, you could do this inside the `dbtable` option:

```py
query = "(SELECT ... FROM BI_Staging.dbo.JOURNAL where ...) AS JOURNAL"

df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(
    url = 'jdbc:sqlserver://<ipaddress>;user=xyz;password=pw',   
    dbtable = query
).load()

df.registerTempTable('JOURNAL')
```